# MySQL 5.27 on Fedora 30 not starting

Tags: mysql, installation

I wanted to install MySQL on my dev Fedora machine for my work. I followed the following tutorial: [Install MySQL 8.0/5.7 on Fedora 30/29](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/). However, when I tried to start the service via `sudo systemctl start mysql.service`, I was not able to.

```
> sudo systemctl start mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

> mysqld
2019-09-17T17:24:18.516842Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-09-17T17:24:18.516948Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/xzhans-xps15-on-fedora.lower-test
2019-09-17T17:24:18.516967Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.27) starting as process 8754 ...
2019-09-17T17:24:18.518447Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/xzhans-xps15-on-fedora.lower-test
2019-09-17T17:24:18.518455Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/xzhans-xps15-on-fedora.lower-test
2019-09-17T17:24:18.518690Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
2019-09-17T17:24:18.518704Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-09-17T17:24:18.518712Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-09-17T17:24:18.518742Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

However, the log file has correct permissions:

```
> sudo ls -la /var/log/mysqld.log 
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql 42880 Sep 17 13:23 /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the obvious question, is mysql configured to be running under the Linux's mysql user or mysql group?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I believe so as those files/directories were created by the application itself. After some further investigation, I believe SELinux is the cause here, like what [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql) is showing. My mentor and I were tired on fighting against SELinux and since we run the prod server with MariaDB on RHEL, we swtiched to MariaDB instead.